# Regex to check if string contains not more than 2 repeated characters

Tags: regex, angular

I am new in Angular 4 and was developing sample application where I have user email id and password field.
In password field I have to check String must not contain more than 2 repeated characters and for that, I have made the following regex:

```
^(?:(.)(?!\1{2,}))*$
```

But this regex fails.

I also tried with the following regex:

```
^((.)(?!\2\2))*$
```

But it angular cli shows error:

> Module parse error: Octal literal in strict mode

Can anyone help me in suitable regex for the above?

Comment: Note: Dot matches any character, including space, tab, bell, Yen symbol, etc. You should probably restrict your inputs more since you're dealing with passwords, unless you consider non-printable characters to be valid password characters (in addition to what I mentioned earlier).

Comment: I don't know Angular, but it seems like an escaping issue. You might want to try and replace "\" with "\\".

Answer (score 3):

A slight variation of your first regex works:

```
^(?:(.)(?!\1\1))+$
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/FiOAEOwcWO).

You only need to check that there aren't *two* repeats, since that is true for all cases of "more than 1".

In English, the regex says "composed entirely of characters that aren't followed by 2 copies of themselves".